# how do I replace part of text in textbox in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a problem about using c# in word automation. 
My problem is I want to replace part of text in a textbox,
ex: *"ABC  12345"* and replace 12345 by *"123"*, as a result, *"ABC  123"*
But I don't know how to get part of text in textbox, I use

```
object firstshape = 1;
string text = w_Doc.shapes.get_Item(ref firstshape).TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
```

to get the original text in textbox,but i don't know how to get the range of part text.
Is there any solution to get any range of text in textbox? thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Why not use [string.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) like: `text = text.Replace("12345","123");`

Comment: or you could try remove and insert

Comment: You can try to ask google

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace like this

```
    string Replace = "12345"; 
    string ReplaceWith = "123"
    text = text.Replace("12345","123")
```

Comment: I know this method. My problem is the string "12345" will change day by day. Therefore, I have to use the position(Last 5 characters) to replace the text, sorry for describing my problem unclearly! Thanks in advance again!

Comment: I think you can read this calls methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx but you can use split...

Answer (score 0):

To get last 5 characters use this:

```
string text = w_Doc.shapes.get_Item(ref firstshape).TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
text = text.Substring(text.Length - 5, 5);
text = text.Replace(text, "123"); //to replace
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq

```
string text = "ABC 12345";
string toReplace = text.Split().SkipWhile(x => x == "ABC").First();
```